# Enable default import with MUI for performance

Tags: visual-studio-code, import, material-ui, bundle

Is there any Eslint config or plugin that auto-fix or converts named imports into default imports for MUI components with VSCode?

Check here the MUI guide https://mui.com/material-ui/guides/minimizing-bundle-size/